# Is the private part present on every profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

In my profile page, there is a section below "*bio*","*visit*","*stats*" named "*private*". This part contains 2 things:

1. **Real name**
2. **My Email**

For other users, I find that there is no such *private* when I view their profiles.
So mainly for privacy, I tried to erase my real name and also my email via "*edit*". But it still remained. Can anyone tell me if this "*private*" exists for all and only the user himself can view this? Or is it that there is some kind of an option to do so which others have used but I cannot find?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me if this "private" exists for all and only the user himself can view this?

Yes, exactly. That's what "private" means.

Actually, moderators (those with a diamond after their names) and select Stack Exchange employees with privileged access can also view the information you enter there. So it's not *just* you. But site members at large cannot.

Comment: Thanks. And strictly no offence to anybody, but is there any chance of misuse of one's "private" information in any way whatsoever ? In that case, tell me how I erase the details from there. And once again NO offence to anybody. Its just for sake of privacy.

Comment: @Aniket That's up to you on who you trust. The site moderators that can see that info are [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators); they were chosen by public site election (see the 'elected 201*' links there for their platforms) and have agreed to abide by the [SE moderator agreement](http://physics.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement). In addition, Stack Exchange developers have access to that information. If you're worried that either group may misuse the information, you should remove it.

Comment: Similarly, if you're worried Stack Exchange might get hacked or suffer a data breach, you should remove information whose leakage you'd be uncomfortable with. [I personally feel SE is particularly open and sound about their security practices, and they're under the glaring scrutiny of stackoverflow and serverfault - but the call is as always yours.]

Comment: @Aniket If you don't know or can't figure out **how** to remove that information, that would be another question. And probably one better suited for [Mother.Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) -- but you should try to search extensively for similar questions there before you ask.